# Get categories list with category name in custom WP_List_Table class

Tags: categories, wp-list-table, post-class

Im building a plugin and i made custom wp_list_table class to suit my needs and display items with native wordpress look.

The problem is that i can't get to list categories with categories names.

I use data from database table and list of my categories in database is in comma separated list of categories id's

so the data looks like

```
136, 8, 10, 11, 110
```

And when i  output that on website i get list just like that comma separated

[image: categories list on my plugin]

But i want to display each category name instead of simple id like this so at the end i want to make it display like on wordpress post default list like this

[image]

It doesn't need to be clickable i just want to display category names on my custom class.

Any idea how to achieve this?

EDIT:

Here is the whole class that i currently use

```
class custom_feeds_list_table extends WP_List_Table {
// declare constructor and give some basic params
function __construct() {
    global $status, $page;
    $message = null;
    $type = null;

    parent::__construct(array(
        'singular' => 'custom-feed',
        'plural' => 'custom-feeds',
    ));
}

//List all columns that we want to display in table
function get_columns() {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
        'feedname' => __('Feed Name', 'vt-translate'),
        'provider' => __('Selected provider', 'vt-translate'),
        'searchterm' => __('Searchterms', 'vt-translate'),
        'numvideos' => __('Videos to pull', 'vt-translate'),
        'post_category' => __('Categories', 'vt-translate'),
        'feedstatus' => __('Status', 'vt-translate'),
    );
    return $columns;
}

//Select which columns are sortable
function get_sortable_columns() {
    $sortable_columns = array(
        'feedname' => array('feedname', true),
        'provider' => array('provider', false),
        'searchterm' => array('searchterm',false),
        'numvideos' => array('numvideos',false),
        'feedstatus' => array('feedstatus', false),
    );
    return $sortable_columns;
}

// Default column render is required
function column_default($item, $column_name) {
    return $item[$column_name];
}

//Bulk action for delete 
function get_bulk_actions() {
    $actions = array(
        'update' => 'Update',
        'enable' => 'Enable',
        'disable' => 'Disable',
        'delete' => 'Delete'
    );
    return $actions;
}

//Process bulk action in database
function process_bulk_action() {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_feeds';

    if ('enable' === $this->current_action()) {
        $ids = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
        if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);

        $this->type = 'updated';
        $this->message = __('No feed selected to enable.', 'custom-feeds');

        if (!empty($ids)) {
            $wpdb->query("UPDATE $custom_table SET feedstatus = 1 WHERE id IN($ids)");
            $this->type = 'updated';
            $this->message = __('Selected feeds are enabled, your website will be updated with enabled feeds at scheduled time.', 'custom-feeds');
        }
    }
    if ('disable' === $this->current_action()) {
        $ids = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
        if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);

        $this->type = 'updated';
        $this->message = __('No feed selected to disable.', 'custom-feeds');

        if (!empty($ids)) {
            $wpdb->query("UPDATE $custom_table SET feedstatus = 0 WHERE id IN($ids)");
            $this->type = 'updated';
            $this->message = __('Selected feeds are disabled, your website will no longer get updates of disabled feeds.', 'custom-feeds');
        }
    }
    if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
        $ids = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
        if (is_array($ids)) $ids = implode(',', $ids);

        $this->type = 'updated';
        $this->message = __('No feed selected to delete.', 'custom-feeds');

        if (!empty($ids)) {
            $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $custom_table WHERE id IN($ids)");
            $this->type = 'updated';
            $this->message = __('Selected feeds are deleted, your website will no longer get updates from deleted feeds. ', 'custom-feeds');
        }
    }
}

//Prepare items to show in list
function prepare_items() {
    global $wpdb;
    $evg_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_feeds';

    $per_page = $this->get_items_per_page('feeds_per_page', 20);
    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();

    $columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = array();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

    // here we configure table headers, defined in our methods
    $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();

    // process bulk action if any
    $this->process_bulk_action();

    // will be used in pagination settings
    $total_items = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $custom_table");

    // prepare query params, as usual current page, order by and order direction
    $paged = isset($_REQUEST['paged']) ? max(0, intval($_REQUEST['paged']) - 1) : 0;
    $orderby = (isset($_REQUEST['orderby']) && in_array($_REQUEST['orderby'], array_keys($this->get_sortable_columns()))) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'id';
    $order = (isset($_REQUEST['order']) && in_array($_REQUEST['order'], array('asc', 'desc'))) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'desc';

    //Define item aray
    $this->items = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $custom_table ORDER BY $orderby $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", $per_page, $paged), ARRAY_A);

    // configure pagination
    $this->set_pagination_args(array(
        'total_items' => $total_items,
        'per_page' => $per_page,
        'total_pages' => ceil($total_items / $per_page)
    ));
}

//Input checkbox for id
function column_cb($item) {
    return sprintf(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="%s" />',
        $item['id']
    );
}

//Display feed name column with buttons
function column_feedname($item) {
    $actions = array(
        'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=custom-feed&action=edit&id=%s">%s</a>', $item['id'], __('Edit', 'custom-feeds')),
        'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=delete&id=%s">%s</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], $item['id'], __('Delete', 'custom-feeds')),
    );

    return sprintf('%s %s',
        '<a href="?page=custom-feed&action=edit&id=' . $item['id'] . '">' . $item['feedname'] . '</a>',
        $this->row_actions($actions)
    );
}

//Display feed status column
function column_feedstatus($item) {
    return sprintf(
        ($item['feedstatus'] == true) ? '<div style="color:#006505">Active</div>' : '<div style="color:#AA0000">Inactive</div>'
    );
}

//Display category column 
function column_post_category($item) {
    return sprintf(
        $item['post_category']
    );
}
```

}

As you can see the category column function is at the end and i only use basic code

```
        return sprintf(
        $item['post_category']
    );
```

which will return raw data from the database, and that is only ID's of categories with comma separated numbers

```
136, 8, 10, 11, 110
```

I know if i use this in theme somewhere like this

```
$cats = $item['post_category'];
```

it will return

```
$cats = 136, 8, 10, 11, 110
```

than

```
$categories = get_categories( array('include' => $cats) );
```

and in the end

```
foreach($categories as $single_cat){
   echo $single_cat->cat_name;
}
```

it will echo the name of every category.

But that's not the case here, this doesn't work in wp_list_table class for some reason so im looking for some other solution. I also looked at wordpress wp_list_table class in included php file but couldn't find anything related to category.

Comment: Post the code for your class, please

Comment: I updated the post to show you my class, and i have been searching for little more about the issue. So far i think my best solution is to use wp_list_categories to list all cats, and customize it with custom walker just to find out more on how to customize walker.

Comment: Where is this code? Where are you using it?

Comment: Im using it on my plugin on custom options page to list all the inputs i have previously put in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to test/debug this kind of question since it is dependent upon a lot of code but it looks to me like you just need to break apart your comma separated list, get the category data, and print the names. [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) and [`wp_list_pluck()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) should make that pretty easy.

```
//Display category column 
function column_post_category($item) {
    $c = get_categories(array('include' => $item['post_category']));
    $c = wp_list_pluck($c,'name');
    $c = implode(', ',$c);
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: Yes yes this did the trick from all the tests that i did i always got back the array and tried to isolate only names from array but no luck. looks like wp_list_pluck does that job i didn't even know that this exists. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It isn't hard to get the names with a `foreach` loop. `wp_list_pluck()` just makes it easy.

Comment: Well you see the code i posted in my question with foreach loop i used it in themes many times, there was theme recently i built where i had to pull specific categories by their id's and worked perfectly to display name and description. But for some reason it doesn't work in walker at least not from what i was trying. Anyway i have a problem when there are 2 or more children categories it doesn't display them in the list now.

Comment: You mean "categories that are children of the IDs in your list"?

Comment: No, sorry i just jumped into conclusions too early, one of my grandchildren category was empty so i just added 'hide_empty' => 0 into get_categories to show missing category.